# UICollectionView not displaying cells after fast scroll

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView that while scroll in occasions stops updating cells.
It load a few cells but when I scroll down or up the rest of the UIcollectionView is empty although the contensize is bigger that the few cells visibles sizes.

It happens more when I scroll really fast, randomly cellForItemAtIndexPath stops being called and the UICollectionView only shows the last loaded cells, with the rest of the space empty.

Here is my code:

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([NewsCollectionViewCell class]) bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([NewsCollectionViewCell class])];

[self.collectionView registerClass:[NewsHeaderCollectionReusableView class]  forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([NewsHeaderCollectionReusableView class])];
```

## pragma mark UICollectionViewDataSource

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
 numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.newsArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NewsCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([NewsCollectionViewCell class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell refreshWithContentModel:self.newsArray[indexPath.item]];

return cell;
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
       viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                             atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NewsHeaderCollectionReusableView *collectionReusableView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([NewsHeaderCollectionReusableView class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (self.newsArray.count) {
    [collectionReusableView refreshWithContentModel:self.newsArray[0]];
}

return collectionReusableView;
}
```

## pragma mark UICollectionViewDelegate

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.item == self.newsArray.count - 1) {
    [self addMoreNews]; // add items to array and call collection reloaddata
}
}
```

## pragma mark UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
return CGSizeMake(ceilf(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width / 3.0) - 10, ceilf(self.collectionView.bounds.size.height / 3.0));
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, ceilf(self.collectionView.bounds.size.height / 2.0));
}
```

Comment: Did you check by assign only color with your cell? Because some time issue in cell data

Comment: Yes, showing only cells with background color without data have the same issue

Comment: That's great so you just need to check your data for cells which are not showing proper data and issue will solved

Comment: It's not the data. After scroll for some time, cellForItemAtIndexPath stops being called and only are visible the cells that were in screen before this happen. When scroll for the  uicollectionview only these cells are displaying, the rest are missing.

Comment: Can you provide your sample Xcode project or you need to check your new data function. From you are adding, new items in collection view.

Comment: @principeroxido did you found solution for your problem? I have same problem.